# How to open additional modal from modal laravel Livewire?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-livewire-wiremodel

How to open modal from modal and close parent modal? Or How to close current modal and open new one.

My scenario is: user click on generate some token, and I like to show him a new token in new modal because I do not want to show token in the past, just that time it will shows up and will be masked in future. To prevent hackers to use it again in some other places.

Is that possible using [this](https://github.com/wire-elements/modal) package?

I tried using this but this does not work for me:

```
 $this->dispatch(
            event: 'openModal',
            component: 'access-token-show-modal',
            arguments: [
                'token' => $token,
            ],
        );
```